# object.create and chaining objects

Tags: javascript, object

In my code below I'm trying to delegate tasks through chaining objects. My goal is to have the media object at the "top" of the chain and having each instance of a song at the bottom like so: media <-- song <-- songXYZ

JavaScript:

```
var playlistElement = document.getElementById("playlist");

var playButton = document.getElementById("play");
playButton.onclick = function() {
    playlist.play();
    playlist.renderInElement(playlistElement);
};
var nextButton = document.getElementById("next");
nextButton.onclick = function() {
    playlist.next();
    playlist.renderInElement(playlistElement);
};
var stopButton = document.getElementById("stop");
stopButton.onclick = function() {
    playlist.stop();
    playlist.renderInElement(playlistElement);
};

var playlist = {
    init: function() {
        this.songs = [];
        this.nowPlayingIndex = 0;
    },
    add: function(song) {
        this.songs.push(song);
    },
    play: function() {
        var currentSong = this.songs[this.nowPlayingIndex];
        currentSong.play();
    },
    stop: function() {
        var currentSong = this.songs[this.nowPlayingIndex];
        currentSong.stop();
    },
    next: function() {
        this.stop();
        this.nowPlayingIndex++;
        if (this.nowPlayingIndex === this.songs.length) {
            this.nowPlayingIndex = 0;
        }
        this.play();
    },
    renderInElement: function(list) {
        list.innerHTML = "";
        for (var i = 0; i <this.songs.length; i++) {
            list.innerHTML += this.songs[i].toHTML();
        }
    }

};

var media = {
    init: function(title, duration) {
        this.title = title;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.isPlaying = false;
    },
    play: function() {
        this.isPlaying = true;
    },
    stop: function() {
        this.isPlaying = false;
    }
};

var song = Object.create(media);

song = {
    setup: function(title, artist, duration) {
        this.init(title, duration);
        this.artist = artist;
    },
    toHTML: function() {
        var htmlString = '<li';
        if(this.isPlaying) {
            htmlString += ' class="current"';
        }
        htmlString += '>';
        htmlString += this.title;
        htmlString += ' - ';
        htmlString += this.artist;
        htmlString += '<span class="duration">'
        htmlString += this.duration;
        htmlString += '</span></li>';

        return htmlString;
    }
};

playlist.init();

var song1 = Object.create(song);
song1.setup("Here comes the Sun", "The Beatles", "2:54");
var song2 = Object.create(song);
song2.setup("Walking on Sunshine", "Katrina and the Waves", "3:43");

playlist.add(song1);
playlist.add(song2);

playlist.renderInElement(playlistElement);
```

I am having the objects delegate to one another using Object.create().

The song object delegates to the media object via:

```
var song = Object.create(media);
```

and each song I create delegates to the song object via:

```
var song1 = Object.create(song);
```

According to the Chrome dev tools song.isPrototypeOf(song1) === true, but media.isPrototypeOf(song) === false. I've used the same piece of code to link song to media as I did to link song1 to song. Also, I'm told that this.init is not a function. But it should delegate up the chain when not found on the song1 and song objects and find it at the media object.

Here is the JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n3q64nq4/

Comment: `var song = Object.create(media); song = { ... }` will make two objects, the first of which is promptly forgotten about, and second of which is unrelated to `media`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of the problem is, as I said in the comment, that you have two assignments to `song`, the second of which clobbers the first one. You want to either use `Object.assign` or a polyfill/equivalent, or assign the properties directly:

```
song.setup = ...;
song.toHTML = ...;
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize I was obliterating that previously linked object, though I should have caught on to that when I was setting up my individual songs with song.setup...